# react hook checkbox didnt render when value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i got my data from the server and setstate the parent component with new data, this child component checkbox didnt get updated.

Child Component

```
const UrlInput = ({showCheckBox, checkBoxValue, onCheckBoxChange}) => {
    const [checkBoxVal, setCheckBoxVal] = useState(_.isUndefined(checkBoxValue) ? false : checkBoxValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCheckBoxVal(checkBoxValue)
        console.log(checkBoxValue)
    }, [checkBoxValue, checkBoxVal]);


    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="form-group">
        
                  <div className="form-group col-6">
                     <AvInput type="checkbox" name="urlCheckBox" onChange={onCheckBoxChange} value={checkBoxVal}/> Title is clickable
                  </div>
   

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
  );
};

export default UrlInput;
```

Comment: I think `checkBoxValue` in the useEffect array might be unnecessary as the component should rerender if that prop is changed. In fact I don't understand the current useEffect...

Comment: Please show us the parent too, the checkBoxValue prop isn't updated and we can't see that in the child only

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for useEffect in this case, as you are passing the value for checkbox from the parent to child and you have written onChange function in the parent, so whenever you will click the checkbox, the value of the state "checkBoxValue" will be changed and it will re-render the child component. Just make sure you are setting event.target.checked to the state in the child.
You can also replace this line :-
const [checkBoxVal, setCheckBoxVal] = useState(_.isUndefined(checkBoxValue) ? false : checkBoxValue);

with this one:-
const [checkBoxVal, setCheckBoxVal] = useState(checkBoxValue ? checkBoxValue : false);